# What [UML] State chart/diagram modelling tools exist for the .NET ecosystem?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, uml, modeling

- Specifically im looking for ones that come with a .NET API to provide a parser/DOM for the state chart.
- I dont mind if its UML or not.
- Ideally it would integrate well with VS2010 or MSBuild.

Comment: Which version do you have? Ultimate has one build in.

Comment: Ive got VS2010 but it does not come with a UML statechart. I am trying to model state machines

Comment: any updates since 2016 on this?

Comment: Sadly, not that I'm aware of. MSFT seemed to have totally lost interest in their modelling tools and SDK

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found:

- [Tangible T4](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com) (non UML)
- [Sparx EA](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) (indications are this is uses [PIAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch.aspx))
- Visio. Probably also uses PIAs.